# Error 'cannot move out of dereference' when trying to match strings from vector

Tags: rust

I am very new to rust and trying to write a command line utility as a way to learn.

I am getting the list of [`args`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/fn.args.html) and trying to match on them

```
let args = os::args()
//some more code
match args[1].into_ascii_lower().as_slice() {
    "?" | "help" => { //show help },
    "add" => { //do other stuff },
    _ => { //do default stuff }
}
```

this causes this error

```
cannot move out of dereference (dereference is implicit, due to indexing)
match args[1].into_ascii_lower().as_slice() {
      ^~~~~~~
```

I have no idea what that means, but searching yield [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/13031) which I didn't completely get, but changing the `args[1]` to `args.get(1)` gives me another error

```
error: cannot move out of dereference of `&`-pointer
match args.get(1).into_ascii_lower().as_slice() {
      ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the documentation, the type of `into_ascii_lower()` is ([see here](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ascii/trait.OwnedAsciiExt.html)) :

```
fn into_ascii_upper(self) -> Self;
```

It takes `self` directly, not as a reference. Meaning it actually consumes the String and return an other one.

So, when you do `args[1].into_ascii_lower()`, you try to directly consume one of the elements of `args`, which is forbidden. You probably want to make a copy of this string, and call `into_ascii_lower()` on this copy, like this :

```
match args[1].clone().into_ascii_lower().as_slice() {
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: yep, that did it. Thank you very much for the quick reply. The error message threw me off, but I guess it makes sense now. Thanks again.